# Let $X,X_1,X_2,X_3,...$ be positive integer random variables. Show that $X_n \overset{d}{\to} X$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_n=k) = P(X=k)$

Tags: convergence, discrete-distributions

**Question**

Let $X,X_1,X_2,X_3,...$ be positive integer random variables. Show that $X_n \overset{d}{\to} X$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_n=k) = P(X=k)$.

The $\overset{d}{\to}$ denotes convergence in distribution.

**Attempt**

Here I try to show

$$X_n \overset{d}{\to} X \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_n=k) = P(X=k)$$

Let $F(x)$, $F_{X_n}(x)$ be the cdfs of $X,X_n$ respectively. Let $k>0$ and suppose that $k$ is *not* in the support of $X$, i.e. $P(X=k)=0$.

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_n=k)
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left[ P(X_n\leq k) - P(X_n<k) \right] \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left[ F_{X_n}(k) - \lim_{x\to k^-}F_{X_n}(x) \right]\\
&= F(k) - \lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{x\to k^-}F_{X_n}(x)
\end{align}
$$

I get stuck. Not sure where to go forward.

Now suppose that $k>0$ is in the support of $X$, so $P(X=k) >0$. I also get stuck here. Again, I can write

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_n=k)
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left( F_{X_n}(k) - \lim_{x\to k^-}F_{X_n}(x) \right)\\
\end{align}
$$

But convergence in distribution only implies $F_{X_n}(t) \to F(t)$ when $F$ is continuous at $t$. Since $X$ is a discrete random variable, $F$ is not continuous at $k$ in the support. Again, not sure how to move forward?

Comment: Hint: consider the limits of $F_{X_n}(k+1/2)$ and $F_{X_n}(k-1/2)$ as $n\to\infty$ and apply a theorem about limits of differences of sequences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$F$ actually is continuous at all non-integers (where, of course, its graph is horizontal, reflecting zero chance that $X$ will be nonintegral).  Consequently, in particular, the convergence in distribution of the sequence implies convergence at (say) the values $k\pm 1/2,$ from which you may instantly conclude for any integral $k$ that

$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\Pr(X_n=k) &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\Pr(X_n\le k+1/2) - \Pr(X_n\le k-1/2)\right) \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(F_{X_n}(k+1/2) - F_{X_n}(k-1/2)\right)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} F_{X_n}(k+1/2) - \lim_{n\to\infty}F_{X_n}(k-1/2)\\
&= F(k+1/2) - F(k-1/2)\\
&= \Pr(X=k),
\end{aligned}$$

*QED.*

Answer (score 5):

Following on from [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber)'s excellent answer, we can also see that this theory applies for any set of random variables with *countable* support, even if they are not positive integers.  To see this, consider a sequence of random variables with distribution on a countable support $\mathscr{X} \subset \mathbb{R}$.  For any such set, there exist continuous non-decreasing functions $u:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $r:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the property that:

$$x' < r(x) < x < u(x) < x''
\quad \quad \quad \text{for all } \ x' < x < x'' \ \text{ that are all in } \mathscr{X},$$

(Proving this result is a useful follow-up exercise you might like to try.)  It follows that for all $x \in \mathscr{X}$ (and for any random variable in the sequence) we have:

$$\mathbb{P}(X_n = x) 
= \mathbb{P}(r(x) < X_n \leqslant u(x))
= F_{X_n}(u(x)) - F_{X_n}(r(x)).$$

By analogy to the solution for the case of positive integer random variables, we then have:

$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_n = x) 
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Big[ F_{X_n}(u(x)) - F_{X_n}(r(x)) \Big] \\[10pt]
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_{X_n}(u(x)) - \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_{X_n}(r(x)) \\[10pt]
&= F_X(r(x)) - F_X(u(x)) \\[12pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(X = x). \\[10pt]
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Since you seem interested in capturing the essence of the situation--which is always worthwhile--note that smoothness of these functions is of no import.  What ultimately matters is that the support is *discrete:* that is, there is an open neighborhood around each point in the support that intersects the support at that point only.

Comment: @whuber: I have edited to specify continuity instead of smoothness, since continuity makes the limit results easier.  Does this look better to you?

Comment: The point is that you don't need these functions to have much of any properties at all except to identify suitable neighborhoods of $k:$ specifying them just obscures that basic point. The problem is solved simply by restating $\Pr(X_n=x)$ in terms of the probability that $X_n$ lies between two defined values at which $F$ is continuous.  *We don't otherwise care about the properties of $F_n;$* it suffices that $F_n$ converges to $F$ pointwise and is discrete with the same support as $F.$

Comment: Yes, fair enough.